# Плохо работает баланс скобок JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
var str = prompt('Введите строку','');

 function bracked(str) {
    var a = str.match(/\(/gm),
        b = str.match(/\)/gm);
    return a && b ? a.length == b.length : a == b;
}
 alert(bracked(str))
```

**Реализация задания со скобками говорит, что в строке ))(( они расставлены верно**

Comment: Ну так они верно расставлены. В вашей задаче условие - чтоб количество открывающих скобок соотвествовало количеству закрывающих, так что всё отлично работает. В чем вопрос то?

Comment: ну если ввести  ))(( , то покажет верно, мне нужно в таких вариантах что бы выдавало ошибку

Comment: Почему? В чем ошибка то? Чего вы от нас хотите?

Comment: Имеется ввиду чтобы на каждую открывающую скобку имелась своя закрывающая, а открывающая была перед закрывающей. Верно?

Comment: Задание было таково "Написать функцию, которая проверит правильность расстановки круглых скобок
 во введенной строке - принимает в себя строку и возвращает
 true или false в зависимости от того, правильно ли расставлены скобки в строке." Примером выше, я вроде реализовал. Но если я введу в строку закр. скобку, а потом откр. скобку покажет что все верно. как сделать что бы выдавало ошибку в таких вариантах.( не может же скобки закрывается, если они не открыты)

Comment: А где вы учитываете последовательность открытия-закрытия?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const str = prompt('Введите строку', '))((');

const bracked = str => 0 === [...str].reduce((opened, symbol) => {
    switch(true) {
        case opened === false: case opened < 0: return false;
        case symbol == '(': return ++opened;
        case symbol == ')': return --opened;
        default: return opened;
    }
}, 0)

console.log(str, bracked(str))
```

Comment: Красота )).....

Comment: Красота? Ну не знаю, довольно сложно читать такое.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman А преподавателю объяснить - еще сложней, если не шаришь. Всё для молодёжи)

Answer (score 1):

Вот валидатор, который я писал N лет назад. Суть такая, что мы по последовательно идём по строке, и если встречаем элемент из `openers`, то добавляем его индекс в массив `arr`. Если встречаем элемент из `closers`, то сравниваем его индекс с последним числом в массиве `arr` (удаляя его из этого массива) и если оно не равно индексу из `closers`, то валидация не пройдена.

Этот скрипт может свалидировать такие вложенные последовательности различных скобок: `[()](){{}}`

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

function isValid() {
  var str = input.value,
    openers = '<{[(',
    closers = '>}])',
    arr = [],
    valid = true;

  for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (openers.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0) {
      arr.push(openers.indexOf(str[i]));
    } else if (closers.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0) {
      if (closers.indexOf(str[i]) != arr.pop()) {
        valid = false;
      }
    }
  }

  if (arr.length) {
    valid = false;
  }

  input.className = valid ? 'valid' : 'error';
}

input.addEventListener('keyup', isValid)
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

input {
  width: 98%;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.error {
  background-color: #ffc6c6;
}

.valid {
  background-color: #bdffc6;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: зачем использовать индексы, каждый раз их вычисляя причем, если в стек можно складывать сами символы скобок?

Comment: @Grundy попробуйте сделать по вашему методу, я не рассматривал такой алгоритм. Каждый раз вычисляя индекс из чего? Из массива длинной 4-5 элементов? Это задача для РосНано, я такими оптимизациями не занимаюсь :)

Answer (score 0):

в случае одного вида скобок, задачу можно решить просты подсчетом: при открывающей скобке - увеличивать счетчик, при закрывающей - уменьшать.

Если счетчик стал отрицательным - строка некорректная, если по завершении проверки счетчик больше 0, строка некорректная.

```js
var str = '))((';

function bracked(str) {
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == '(') counter += 1;
    else {
      counter -= 1
      if (counter < 0) return false;
    }
  }
  return counter == 0;
}
console.log(bracked('))(('), bracked('()(())()'))
```

Также данную задачу можно решить при помощи стека:

1. если текущий символ открывающая скобка - заносим его в стек
2. если текущий символ закрывающая скобка

   1. выталкиваем символ с вершины стека, если полученный символ не открывающаяся скобка - строка не валидная
   2. если открывающаяся переходим к следующему символу из строки

```js
var str = '))((';

function bracked(str) {
  var stack = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == '(') stack.push('(');
    else {
      var prev = stack.pop();
      if (prev != '(') return false;
    }
  }
  return stack.length == 0;
}
console.log(bracked('))(('), bracked('()(())()'))
```

такой подход довольно просто расширяется на несколько видов скобок. Для этого необходимо добавить объект для соответствия открывающих и закрывающих символов, и вместо открывающих в стек складывать закрывающие.

```js
var str = '))((';

function bracked(str) {
  var bracketmap = {
    '(':')',
    '{':'}',
    '[':']'
  };
  var stack = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] in bracketmap) stack.push(bracketmap[str[i]]);
    else {
      var prev = stack.pop();
      if (prev != str[i]) return false;
    }
  }
  return stack.length == 0;
}
console.log(bracked('([})]'), bracked('([])[{()}]([])'))
```